# NXP Explore NFC using libnfc on Raspberry Pi

Tags: nfc

I am thinking of starting a project where I use the NXP Explore-NFC board for the Raspberry Pi so that I can write NDEF messages to the NFC via an Android device. I currently own the Raspberry Pi and the NXP Explore-NFC board. I have been doing some research and know that you can use the libnfc library with the board. My background is in Java and Android development, so I have very little experience in embedded systems. This is why I wanted to use the libnfc library.

I wanted to know if anyone has managed to get this working with the same NFC board and if so, do I need to learn any new programming languages to achieve this. If anyone has any information about this please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure that NXP Explore-NFC is the perfect board for this (http://www.libnfc.org/community/topic/1245/nxp-explorenfc-with-libnfc/), [this one](http://imall.iteadstudio.com/im130625002.html) has a better support for libnfc

Answer (score 3):

**NXP - EXPLORE-NFC** doesn't support the commonly known [*libnfc*](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Libnfc) [<sup>1</sup>](http://www.libnfc.org/community/topic/1245/nxp-explorenfc-with-libnfc/). It uses the *PN512* chip that is not listed in the [compatibility matrix](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Devices_compatibility_matrix).

However, NXP provides its own library with examples. You can find it [here](http://www.nxp.com/demoboard/PNEV512R.html#documentation).

---

<sup>1</sup> : *NXP EXPLORE-NFC with libnfc* (http://www.libnfc.org/community/topic/1245/nxp-explorenfc-with-libnfc/)

Answer (score 2):

I was looking into the nxppy source codes and found in the comments that the PN512 chip could be compatible with the RC523 chip. Not tested myself but maybe this could get the libnfc connection working.